# Where to put a ViewModel factory in my ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a fairly complicated ViewModel associated with a product listing form, which has a lot of custom default values depending on the currently logged in user.  I'm finding that populating it in my controller is quite a chore.  So I'm thinking of creating a factory class for it, but I'm wondering where in the project structure it would be a best fit.  In the Controllers folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd move it out into a separate Common or Core folder, or Common or Core project for that matter.  If you can decouple the logic that's not specific to MVC, you'll probably be better off in the long run.

Comment: Why would you move it out to a separate project? A folder is perfectly fine for this use, and doesn't require a separate assembly.